# Encode and decode signature in certification generated by forge

Tags: node.js, ssl, node-forge

I am using [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) to generate and validate certificates

I am generating and validating certificates and everything seems to work perfectly, but when it comes to the part where I do need to provide a signature to certificate it fails

To clarify: I need to provide signature to certificate where the signature is hashed using ***RSA***, and the signature contains data about the client and his roles

the way I am creating signature

```
const createSignture = (privateKey, data) => {
  // The signature method takes the data we want to sign, the
  // hashing algorithm, and the padding scheme, and generates
  // a signature in the form of bytes
  const signature = crypto.sign("sha256", Buffer.from(data), {
    key: privateKey,
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING,
  });

  return signature.toString("base64");
};
```

When I am creating a certificate using forge I am doing it like:

```
const cert = forge.pki.createCertificate();
....
cert.signature = createSignture(privateKey, userUniqueId);
...
```

And when I am verifying the certificate, I am trying to verify the signature

```
const verifySignture = (publicKey, signture, data) => {
  // To verify the data, we provide the same hashing algorithm and
  // padding scheme we provided to generate the signature, along
  // with the signature itself, the data that we want to
  // verify against the signature, and the public key
  return crypto.verify(
    "sha256",
    Buffer.from(data),
    {
      key: publicKey,
      padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING,
    },
    signture
  );
};


const certSignture = cert.signature;
const decodedSignature = Buffer.from(forge.util.binary.raw.decode(certSignture)).toString("base64");


verifySignture(publicKey, decodedSignature, userUniqueId) // This always returns false
```

I am not very sure that I should provide the roles, userId etc.. in the signture.

I've tried for many hours and nothing is working so I would really appreciate any help